# Bring recent button in front of others

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have a question that i am animating buttons and place them to one place(where as x position of buttons are different).
i want the recent button(which is clicked) on above of all.i used sendSubViewToBack: method to send previous button to back but this is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try  [bringSubviewToFront](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/bringSubviewToFront%3a)

```
[youtView bringSubviewToFront:youtBtn];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:button];
```

Use your parent view on which buttons are added instead of self.view.

And make sure the order of above code for buttons.

Above code for latest button will come above of all buttons(view).

Answer (score 0):

you can also use following

```
[self.view insertSubview:yourbtn belowSubview:view];
```

Comment: Thanks Brother...Good piece of work and this is new for me..i like it.Thank u